# If Div has certain text inside of it send message to php and then to .txt? JQuery/js/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Cannot get it to work for some reason but what I want to do is ....
If a div has a certain message in it I.E "You have Won" I want to be able to detect it and then send a message of "You Have Won" to php and then into a .txt file so this is how im going about it :

```
var Winner = $("#.notification .title").html();



if($(".notification .title").html() == "You have Won") {
   $.ajax({
    url:'Won.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{Winner:Winner},
    success:function(data){

    } 
}
```

The PHP:

```
<?php 


$Winner = $_POST['Winner'] ? $_POST['Winner'] : 'not set';
$file = fopen('file.txt','a+');
fwrite($file, ' outcome: '.$Winner.' '.PHP_EOL);
fclose($file);


?>
```

No idea why it doesnt work

Also is there any way to "play" the function every 3 seconds?

Basiclly the function isnt checking the div i dont think so I need to make it keep checking it every 3 seconds or so maybe set inveral or set time out? So the question is 
how can make it check the divs contence every 3 seconds?

Comment: When does the div get the title? Is it like this on page load?

Comment: so what is #winner , #notification ??and in which event you trying to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for input ,textarea and dropdown list use .val()  instead of .html() for div ,span ,label  use .text()
this example for input ,textarea and dropdown list

```
var Winner = $(".notification .title").val();  // this will get a value of .title class 
if (Winner == "You have Won") {
   $.ajax({
    url:'Won.php',
    type:'post',
    data:{Winner:Winner},
    success:function(data){
       alert('Data Stored');
    } 
}
```

also if you want to run function every three seconds 
just use

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
// your code here
},3000);
```

to stop interval use

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Finally your code should be like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var Winner = $(".notification .title").text();  // this will get a value of .title class 
    if (Winner == "You have Won") {
       $.ajax({
        url:'Won.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{Winner:Winner},
        success:function(data){
           alert('Data Stored');
        } 
    }
  },3000);
});
```

Please check for Won.php url. I guess you have to use  url:'../Won.php',

Comment: the class is .title of the div not the id if that makes a difference? can i target the class? in var Winner

Comment: you already targeted it with $(".notification .title").text(); .if you try to target .notification  use $(".notification").text();

Comment: the div i want is in a div with the class that has class="notification"  and then i want the "child" div which has a class of class="title" non have ID's so will this work with just class's? and no ID's? if not how to target the class?

Comment: <div class="notification">
            <div class="title gooddog"></div>
            <div class="reason helvetica"></div>
        </div> these are my divs i cant get it to work code im using is this $(document).ready(function(){
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var Winner = $(".notification .title gooddog").text();  // this will get a value of .title class 
    if (Winner == "sqeeeeeak!") {
       $.ajax({
        url:'Won.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{Winner:Winner},
        success:function(data){
           alert('Data Stored');
        } 
    }
  },3000);
});

Comment: you should do 2 variables of that var Winner = $(".notification .title").text(); var reason= $(".notification .reason").text();  or to get both use var Winner = $(".notification").text(); it will give you both of title and reason like (titlereason)

Comment: I only want the title text :) http://jsfiddle.net/abwp5u21/ I just cant get it to work

Comment: In Jsfiddle you must include jquery from your left hand side http://jsfiddle.net/rhw8wj9a/1/

Answer (score 0):

## this should work

## edit

[CORRECTED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8vnzqhre/)

You just overlookedd a couple things:

- forgot preceding comma before `.gooddog`
- you cant reach the URL set in `$.ajax()`. it's relative to your files, not to js fiddle.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/b492befa534a00f9078c11cafa5e1bc8/)

js

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){

  var Winner = $(".gooddog").text();
 if(Winner == "test") {
     console.log('foo');

// would work fine assuming the php is returning or doing what you need
// since relative, will always fail on js fiddle

/*     $.ajax({
      url: "Won.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { Winner : Winner }
    })
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log('foo', data);
    }); */
  }

},1000);
```

Comment: I cant for the life of me get this to work do you know what im doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/abwp5u21/

Comment: dude, gave you two examples, fixed the one you asked and didn't use backwards jquery functions to get text from `<div />` (i.e.) `$().val();` and accepted other answer. Didn't even give you a demo... tisk tisk... and shame on you